# Регистрация домена на личном сервере

Tags: ip, dns, домен

Привет, сообществу.

Возникли проблемки с регистрацией домена, а задача такая: зарегистрировать его, чтобы весь сайт был у меня, на сервере(компьютер с ubuntu 12. 04 LTS, самая последняя, короче) , статистический ip есть, создал анкету на ру-центр, перечислил туда уже 600 рублей, осталось только взять домен, но там написано

[image: dns серверы]

Короче,  помогайте. Что писать в поле имя, а что в поле ip адрес (свой белый, или провайдера, его ip узнал из cmd ipconfig /all). Мне главное, чтоб все было у меня на компьютере, про хостинг не говорите, нет, хочу все сам поднять и администратировать.  Так, что нужно сделать?

**UPD 1**

**Почти зарегестрировал(использую днс регистратора),но вопрос,что в ip писать??**
[image]

Comment: Все понял)Спасибо,а нельзя как-то переправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя кажется не обязательно, а IP делаешь тот статистический, что дал провайдер. Потом поднимаешь днс-сервер у себя, стандартные настройки зоны, всё.

Comment: По моему,не все так просто,мне надо точно

Comment: Потом поднимаешь днс-сервер у себя, стандартные настройки зоны, всё.

Comment: Вот тут поподробнее,вообще новичок в этом деле

Comment: Кстати,спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Вам на своем сервере надо настроить (поднять) bind и в настройках прописать записи типа NS с вашими IP адресами (их должно быть два).

Но есть проще вариант. Перенаправление с ДНс-ов регистратора на ваш сервер. При покупке домена ставите галку на "Использовать ДНС регистратора" (что-то в этом роде). Далее в настройках домена в панеле добавляете запись типа "А":

```
www.mydomain.ru. A IP-adrees вашего сервера
mydomain.ru. A IP-adrees вашего сервера
```

Сохраняете. Ждете сутки и ваш домен будет доступен и направлен на ваш сервер.

Comment: А потом можно будет поменять?И где у ру-центра  использовать днс регистратора??

Comment: Спасибо,большое))стало понятнее

Comment: незнаю, в ру-центре не покупаю... рег.ру - дешевле)))

Comment: Спасибо,а там есть использовать ДНС регистратора

Comment: Конечно есть, у всех регистраторов есть.