# Регистрация домена (на личном сервере)

Tags: ip, dns, домен

Привет, сообществу.Возникли проблемки с регистрацией домена, а задача такая: зарегистрировать его, чтобы весь сайт был у меня, на сервере(компьютер с ubuntu 12. 04 LTS, самая последняя, короче) , статистический ip есть, создал анкету на ру-центр, перечислил туда уже 600 рублей, осталось только взять домен, но там написано:![Тут картинку посмотрите][1]  [1]: [http://i.imgur.com/CCj5rO8.jpgКороче](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rditV.jpg), помогайте. Что писать в поле имя, а что в поле ip адрес (свой белый, или провайдера, его ip узнал из cmd ipconfig /all). Мне главное, чтоб все было у меня на компьютере, про хостинг не говорите, нет, хочу все сам поднять и администратировать. Так, что нужно сделать?Посоветовали поднять днс-сервер, но как это делать, вообще новичок в этом деле, подскажите ,пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регистрация домена на личном сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197639/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну и здесь подскажу ))

Значит так, лучшим выбором, по моему мнению является сервер bind.

Дальше идёшь в гугл и пишешь "начальная настройка bind", если попадёшь на [opennet.ru](http://opennet.ru/).. а, хотя сразу можешь идти туда и читать про настройку, но сначала лучше прочитать вообще про ДНС [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS)

Comment: Спасибо)начал понимать маленько

Comment: ну тут всё не очень сложно, интуитивно понятно, зачем нужна распределённая система имён, потом понимаешь их организацию, потом своё место в системе, потом твой днс работает )

Answer (score 0):

Нужна пряма зона или так же - А запись для твоего домена (т.е. соответствие твоего домена ипу). Можешь попросить провайдера разместить ее у себя на DNS сервере. Обычно это не бесплатно.

Comment: Да не нужна тут "прямая зона", и для чего вся эта тряхомудия? Можно смело воткнуть корневые DNS 8.8.8.8 и 8.8.4.4! У меня - работает, и плевать мне на всё остальное!!!

Answer (score -1):

А чего тут делать-то? Регистрируй домен, и переводи его на свои сервера. Чего здесь непонятного?

Сайт есть? Тогда выбираем доменного регистратора. Далее покупаем домен. Регистрируем домен у Регистратора - это обязательно! Теперь вы у регистратора привязываете  ваш сайт к вашему домену.  Я понятно объяснил?

Comment: и зачем столько вопросительных и восклицательных знаков?